# Asynchronous random file access with FileStream Read vs ReadAsync in a loop / parallel (ReadAsync is slow)

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, filestream

As we were switching from synchronous to asynchronous code we found that reading small chunks of data across a huge file (in a loop or in parallel) was much slower than using synchronous code.

In our example we need to retrieve 8000 samples of 1000 bytes uniformly across a huge file.

Below are the results we are getting. Synchronous code is at least 8 times faster. Any suggestions on how to speed up the async code? Full solution is here: https://github.com/virzak/DotNetPerformance

```
                     Method |       Job | Runtime |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
--------------------------- |---------- |-------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
           ReadSamplesAsync |  ClrQuick |     Clr | 625.99 ms | 14.153 ms |  8.422 ms |
 ReadSamplesInParallelAsync |  ClrQuick |     Clr | 627.81 ms | 15.147 ms | 10.019 ms |
                ReadSamples |  ClrQuick |     Clr |  40.56 ms |  3.257 ms |  2.155 ms |
           ReadSamplesAsync | CoreQuick |    Core | 327.29 ms | 39.089 ms | 25.855 ms |
 ReadSamplesInParallelAsync | CoreQuick |    Core | 318.27 ms | 13.937 ms |  9.218 ms |
                ReadSamples | CoreQuick |    Core |  39.74 ms |  2.531 ms |  1.674 ms |
```

Our code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DotNetPerformance
{
    public class ReadAsyncLoop
    {

        public ReadAsyncLoop(string fileName)
        {
            FilePath = fileName;
            var fi = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            FileSize = fi.Length;
            SampleCount = FileSize / sampleSize;
        }

        const int sampleSize = 1000;
        const int sampleCount = 8000;

        long SampleCount { get; }
        string FilePath { get; }
        long FileSize { get; }


        public async Task CompareRunningTimes()
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            await ReadBytesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"FINISHED (Async) in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            sw.Restart();
            await ReadBytesInParallelAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"FINISHED (Async in parallel) in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            sw.Restart();
            ReadBytes();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"FINISHED (Sync) in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

        }

        public async Task ReadBytesInParallelAsync()
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous);

            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
            {
                var sampleIndex = (long)(i / (double)SampleCount * FileSize);
                var bytes = new byte[sampleSize];
                tasks.Add(ReadSampleBytesFromFileAsync(fs, sampleIndex, bytes));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task ReadBytesAsync()
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
            for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
            {
                var sampleIndex = (long)(i / (double)SampleCount * FileSize);
                var bytes = new byte[sampleSize];
                await ReadSampleBytesFromFileAsync(fs, sampleIndex, bytes).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        public void ReadBytes()
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096);
            for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
            {
                var sampleIndex = (long)(i / (double)SampleCount * FileSize);
                var bytes = new byte[sampleSize];
                ReadSampleBytesFromFile(fs, sampleIndex, bytes);
            }
        }

        static private async Task ReadSampleBytesFromFileAsync(FileStream fs, long sampleGlobalIndex, byte[] sampleBytes, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            var seekPosition = sampleGlobalIndex * sampleSize;
            var lActual = fs.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            await fs.ReadAsync(sampleBytes, 0, sampleSize, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        static private void ReadSampleBytesFromFile(FileStream fs, long sampleGlobalIndex, byte[] sampleBytes)
        {
            var seekPosition = sampleGlobalIndex * sampleSize;
            var lActual = fs.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            fs.Read(sampleBytes, 0, sampleSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual physical drive that you're reading from only has one disk head, and can only be reading from one place.  Reading from *super tiny* sections, randomly all over the disk, tanks your performance.  Read large chunks of contiguous data.

Comment: This is expected as there a bit more overhead for async code to manage the `Tasks`. The advantage is that you get more throughput because the thread is not waiting to read from the disk (as with synchronous code), so it can go off and do something else (potentially).

Comment: @Servy, reading tiny sections from the disk is a requirement - nothing can be done about it. My question is why such a difference in performance between async and sync.

Comment: @jag, I understand the overhead part and it really is slight when reading large chunk once. But why is it x8 performance when you read in a loop?

Comment: `ReadBytesInParallelAsync` is incorrect. Your `Seek` operations will walk all over each other. You should be using something like Overlapped I/O for parallel operations on a single file handle.

Comment: Likely, the file is cached in your benchmark. There is no IO. The difference is all async overhead which is expected. It's just that few people realize that this overhead exists. Solution: Do not use async IO if it does not benefit you.

Comment: @usr, Please elaborate on how is there caching? You'll get the same result if you point the benchmark to a brand new file and let the sync run first.

Keeping sync functions is an obvious solution, but that means introducing sync functions for IO operations, something that does against the push to migrate old code to asynchronous.

Comment: After the code has first touched the entire file it is cached in kernel memory. After that point there is only CPU usage.

Comment: On the very first run:

FINISHED (Sync) in 83222 ms
FINISHED (Async) in 294 ms
FINISHED (Async In Parallel) in 281 ms  

On the next runs it reads from the cached memory:

FINISHED (Sync) in 98 ms
FINISHED (Async) in 310 ms
FINISHED (Async In Parallel) in 261 ms

The file was much bigger than the RAM, but the OS seems cached only the chunks which you accessed.