# For asynchronous file I/O tasks, does the stream itself need to be asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

This is what is typically done if you want to use, say, `StreamWriter` to write to a file asynchronously:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    string fileName = "output.txt";
    string message = "Something";
    
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
}
```

However, I noticed that the `FileStream` class has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) which allows you to indicate the stream itself is asynchronous. By default, `useAsync` is `false` if you use a different constructor, i.e., the stream is synchronous by default (?) . Does this mean that in the code above, it's better to open an asynchronous stream and then pass it to `StreamWriter` like this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    string fileName = "output.txt";
    string message = "Something";
    
    using var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, true);
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
}
```

Does this way make any difference here (or in general), and is it better asynchronous code?

Comment: ipersonally, i find the description of `useAsync` quite enlightening. the TLDR would be: using async _can_ increase performance, if the application around it is programmed right, or it can decrease it if the application isn't.

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-the-ui-thread) interesting. Currently the asynchronous filesystem APIs are not implemented efficiently in .NET. If you set the `useAsync` to `true`, the operation will be considerably slower, while being still mostly synchronous.