# Parallel task works very slow inside docker

Tags: c#, multithreading, docker, parallel-processing

My local laptop has 4 cores and 32GB RAM.

My EC2 in c5.8xlarge - 32 cores and 64GB GB.

I have a job that runs some parallel processes. Here is a piece of representative code.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(jobList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, job=>{
    //each job includes parameters for a year to do some work for each month
    
     var subTasks = new List<Task>();
     for (var m = 1; m < 13; m++){
          var subTasks = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
               //process task
               //each task include HTTP calls, SQL process, S3 csv loads and save
          });
          subTasks.Add(subTasks);
     }
     Task.WaitAll(subTasks.ToArray());
 });
```

When I run the code on my local computer, it takes 30-40 seconds. However, I run on an EC2 server, and it takes over 150 seconds. I deployed my project as a docker container on EC2. In my local, I run the code on IIS Express.

Also, I tested the process inside single task performance on both sides.  On EC2, a single task takes less time than my local. If a task takes 10 seconds on my local, it takes 6 seconds on EC2.

Does anyone know the possible reason why this difference occurs? Is it related to the warming-up application?

**NOTE:**
The question is how a weak local computer can be 4 times faster than a strong server. Namely, my code is run fast on my local computer. But in the server, running is 4 times slower. Why?

There are two structural differences between my local and the server. Docker + nginx and IIS Express. The server capacity, bandwidth, and network distance are better than the local.

Comment: The relevant code is missing so it's impossible to help. The question's code is wrong to begin with. `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't process anything in parallel, it only starts some tasks, and more specifically, 13 tasks for every item in `JobList`. It's those tasks that actually do the job. For each job item though, the iteration *block* waiting for the tasks to complete.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Process items in a queue? Why start 13 task for each job item? For starters you could use an `ActionBlock<T>` which already processes queued items using one or more worker tasks. You could use `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(jobList,(job,cancel)=>Task.Run(()=>ProcessJob(job),cancel));`. For the job queue itself you could use a `Channel<T>` class

Comment: What is the task doing?  It could be that you are not CPU bound, but likely I/O bound for example.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove the `List<Task>` shenanigans, and process the 12 months of each job serially. Then experiment with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, starting with a small value like `2`. Increase the value gradually, and see at what level the performance stops improving.

Comment: Parallel.For/ForEach is intended for data parallel computations. Tasks are typically used for IO computations or task parallelism. Using tasks inside a parallel loop can be problematic, especially if used for computations rather than IO. So I would second the suggestion to remove all the task shenanigans.

Comment: You could also consider implementing task-parallelism on top of the existing data-parallelism. You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597408/async-file-i-o-overhead-in-c-sharp/68600967#68600967) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602684/process-files-concurrently-and-asynchronously/62613098#62613098). The performance benefits might not be large enough to justify the complexity though.

Comment: Add the relevant code in the question. The current code is both buggy and quite possible repeats the *same* operation multiple times. All AWS SDK operations have asynchronous versions which means you can use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to execute them concurrently, controlling the number of concurrent tasks with a simple setting

Comment: `HTTP calls, SQL process, S3 csv loads and save` is neither complex nor unusual. I have *several* jobs that download stuff from S3 or remote services, process the CSV or other results, use SqlBulkCopy to write the data to a database. I use either Dataflow blocks like TransformBlock or Channels and Parallel.ForEachAsync

Comment: The question is how a local computer can be faster than a strong server. Not about SQLs or HTTPs.

Comment: I know it doesn't explain all the difference but think about the IPC. C5 are on 6-7 years old architecture running at about 3.0-3.1 ghz per core. You max parallelism use 10 core max and it could be 2 as it's not really controllable. If you compare to a 13th gen intel cpu at 5 ghz you are looking at a difference of about 90% faster on 13th gen than the xeon they use for a single core. Note the % include gen leap increment in IPC

Comment: Please post your solution below, in the section marked "answer" and once able, click the check mark on the side to mark the question as having an accepted answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I replaced `Parallel.Foreach` with `SemaphoreSlim`. And Bingo!!! It works as I expect. Only 14 seconds. This is approximately one month of process running time.

I think this is related to `@JonasH` and `@Franck` comments. Some codes work differently in different environments. I am not sure which difference results in this condition and how. Maybe IIS, maybe Windows, or Docker. I think this is a case for experts.

```
 var monthlyTasks = new List<Task>();
 using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(120))
 {    
    foreach (var process in processList) //processList include all monthly jobs
    {
          concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
          var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
               try
               {
                  RunMontlyProccess(process);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                  _log.Error("ParallelProcess: " + process.Id + ", message:" + ex.Message, ex);
               }
               finally
               {
                   concurrencySemaphore.Release();
               }
          });
          monthlyTasks.Add(t);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(monthlyTasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Functionally this code is not different than the code in the question. The level of concurrency is 150 instead of 120, the behavior in case of an error is worse (no fail-fast), and there are 9 less blocked `ThreadPool` threads. This is certainly far from being the best way of conducting parallel processing, and I wouldn't advice anyone to imitate it.

Comment: I think your comment isn't related to the question. The number of concurrencys isn't important for the case. I tried with 90,100,120,150... There is no big difference. The question is how a weak local computer can be 4 times faster than a strong server when using `parallel.foreach`.

Comment: If the question is how a weak local computer can be 4 times faster than a strong server, then your answer does not answer the question. Making speculations doesn't count as answer, and accompanying these speculations with inadvisable coding patterns doesn't make your answer more valuable either.