# Async task is blocking the UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, streamwriter

Hello esteemed colleagues, I need to save to a text file every time I get a new message from my serial port into my `RichTextBox`. I'm trying to use `async` and `await` it won't block the UI while saving the text file, but unfortunately I'm doing something wrong because it still blocking. Please, what am I doing wrong?

`TextChanged` event handler from `RichTextBox`:

```
private async void rtb_msg_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_save.Enabled = true;
    rtb_msg.ScrollToCaret();
    rcvFlag = true;
    await SaveFile();
}
```

Async `SaveFile` method:

```
private async Task SaveFile()
{
    if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0 && rcvFlag == true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(reportFolder + reportFile))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(rtb_msg.Text);
        }
        rcvFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Async != multi threading

Comment: Does the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` serve as a placeholder for an actual long-running method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part will definitely block your UI thread:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Not sure why it's there, but if you replace it with an async version, it should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use `Thread.Sleep` in async methods. Use `Task.Delay` and `Task.Run` instead

```
private Task SaveFileAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0 && rcvFlag == true)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(reportFolder + reportFile))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(rtb_msg.Text);
            }
            rcvFlag = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for the option to do the Task.Run. But keep in mind it only makes sense when you have a lot of CPU bound work, like a enormous calculation. Which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Stefan the `Task.Run` also makes sense for I/O-bound work for which an asynchronous API does not exist. In some cases it might even be preferable to use `Task.Run` instead of the existing asynchronous API, because the corresponding synchronous API [is more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-c-sharp-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-ui-thread/63218926#63218926).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: yes, that is entirely correct, I oversimplified.