# Async / await made synchronous - a silver bullet for any case?

Tags: c#, async-await

I think this is one of the most horrific topics in async/await, probably only for C# as other languages don't seem to have these horrible constraints. Tons of questions and blogs are written for this particular problem and how to supposedly deal with it. After many years, I am still not certain how to approach it...

### The problem

What we encounter quite frequently is where we are implementing our view models. There we have the typical `RelayCommand` or with Mvvm Community we even get the `AsyncRelayCommand`. Neither of them allow to have an **async** `CanExecute` method. The constructors of these types require a `Func<bool>` for the `canExecute` argument.

In some cases, we need to call into async code from the `canExecute` as follows

```
UpdateCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Update, SomeCanExecuteMethod);

...
...

private bool SomeCanExecuteMethod()
{
    return _someDependency.DoSomethingAsync().Result;
}
```

### The question

Now let's assume we've done everything as we were supposed to in the implementation of `DoSomethingAsync` and every await call is properly configured with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Is the above construction in danger of causing a deadlock?

### Alternative one

Assuming the answer to the above is yes, will this **always** prevent a potential deadlock?

```
private bool SomeCanExecuteMethod()
{
    return Task.Run(async () => 
    {
       return await _someDependency.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).Result;
}
```

I'll be honest, I can't explain why this may solve the problem. I remember something (vaguely) that this has somewhat of a side effect, settings the synchronization context to null, which on its turn will prevent a deadlock from happening.

### Alternative two

Since alternative one (if correct) feels a bit like "side effect programming", would it then be better to be explicit and set the synchronization context null explicitly?

```
    
private bool SomeCanExecuteMethod()
{
    var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    var result = _someDependency.DoSomethingAsync().Result;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    return result;
}
```

NOTE: dealing with mixing up asynchronous code and synchronous code is something we encounter on more occasions than just this MVVM example. We also have to deal with legacy which in some cases is simply too invasive to refactor completely to async await all the way down. So we are looking for "the silver bullet" to deal with mixing asynchronous code and synchronous code, if there is any...

Comment: Related: [Calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously).

Comment: I recommend watching this (great) talk to get a deeper understanding of async/wait in .net https://youtu.be/zhCRX3B7qwY?si=i3BjCLre4XWp-U6_

Comment: @Philippe I've watched the first 20 minutes of the [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhCRX3B7qwY "Correcting Common Async/Await Mistakes in .NET 8 - Brandon Minnick - Copenhagen DevFest 2023"). It's full of erroneous information. For example the speaker seems to be under the impression that async methods run on threads, which [is typically not the case](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html "There is no thread"). I don't recommend this video. Any solid info in there is outvalued by the cost of learning falsehoods that you'll later have to unlearn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Theodor answered quite succinctly, [there is no silver bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77401778/263693). This is a followup answer to explain a bit more about your specific situation.

> Neither of them allow to have an async CanExecute method.

Consider what `CanExecute` means, and what `async` means.

`CanExecute` is usually used by the OS to determine whether a button is enabled or disabled. The UI is in the middle of drawing the screen *right now*, and it needs to know whether the button is enabled or disabled *right now*.

`async` is usually used by an application to perform some kind of I/O, usually an API or database call. It's a way for an application to initiate some operation and then later respond to the operation completing.

Clearly, these two are not *meant* to go together. If the OS says to the application, "hey, I'm drawing the screen right now; is this button enabled?" and the application says, "hold on with that screen refresh; let me call this API and/or query this DB to find out", then your users are in for a world of hurt. That's just a terrible user experience no matter how the code is mangled to make it work.

This is why `CanExecute` is synchronous, and no one has even considered making it asynchronous.

> we encounter quite frequently

You should not encounter this frequently. It sounds like you might want to reconsider how your application's UI is handled. I wrote a series of articles years ago on mixing `async` with UI concerns; [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) is IMO the most helpful.

> I think this is one of the most horrific topics in async/await, probably only for C# as other languages don't seem to have these horrible constraints.

Certainly they have the same constraints. Furthermore, most languages also restrict the developers to a more narrow set of solutions.

Consider the equivalent scenario using JavaScript + React. The rough equivalent of `CanExecute` is the `render` method of a React component. `render` is called when the browser/OS is displaying the UI. And that `render` method can't be `async` - it's just flat-out not allowed. Just like `CanExecute` can't be `async`.

The standard Reactish pattern of handling this is to *not show the button at all* until the async work is complete (and the application knows whether the button is enabled). So `render` returns "no UI" until the `async` is complete, and *then* `render` is called again with the updated props and returns a button with the proper enabled state.

So, JavaScript + React have the same constraints. They also restrict the developers more: it's not possible in JavaScript to block on asynchronous code. C# *allows* you to provide a poor user experience by blocking on asynchronous code (even though it's strongly discouraged); JavaScript doesn't even *allow* you to do that. JavaScript *forces* you to fix the application structure. Which is not a bad idea at all.

> We also have to deal with legacy which in some cases is simply too invasive to refactor completely to async await all the way down.

And here's the real reason for C#'s design decisions. Yes, they allow a poor user experience by allowing blocking on asynchronous code... for backwards compatibility reasons. There were a lot of applications that synchronously blocked the UI, and C# still allows that. It's a pragmatic decision.

> So we are looking for "the silver bullet"

As noted by Theodor, there sadly isn't one. There are a [few different techniques](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), but each has their drawbacks and none of them work in all scenarios.

Comment: Your explanation of canExecute and "right now" does make an awful lot of sense. +1 this actually helps me a lot.

Comment: So I think my question in two fold then. On one end, it's about trying to make canExecute async, which I see now is backwards and wrong. But then, there are those many occasions where we do need to mix async with sync. Is there a suggestion you could make how to achieve that which **guarantees** that it won't deadlock? Wrapping the async part in another `Task.Run` or temporarily setting the synchronization context to null ?

Comment: You can guarantee it won't deadlock; either `Task.Run` or setting SyncCtx to `null` will do that. But it won't guarantee the code will *work* correctly. See [the last link in my answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). As an example, if the async code does an await and then touches the UI, then there isn't a solution; you can prevent deadlocks but you'll get a cross-thread exception.

Comment: Ah, you are that same guy ;-). Haha I've read your blogs on the topic, didn't recognize the name, did recognize the photo when opening the page :). Also to you, thanks for the input and explanations. I will reread things and might come back with the question that I simply can't put to words atm. But a few things are definitely clear now. Thx

Comment: "JavaScript doesn't even allow you to do that" Well, it makes it harder, not impossible.  You could make your own busyloop if you were really committed.

Comment: "You can guarantee it won't deadlock;" No, you can't.  At least in the general case.  Just because you call the async method via Task.Run doesn't mean it can't get ahold of a synchronization context that you're blocking.  It just means it can't specifically get it from SyncronicationContext.Current.  But in many UI contexts the message loop is accessible in other ways that code often will use to send messages to the message loop that you're blocking.  The only way you could be sure there's no deadlock is if you're blocking a thread that isn't a message loop (or equivalent).

Answer (score 4):

There is no silver bullet.

1. If you wrap the call in [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run), the asynchronous method will be invoked on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). This is not acceptable in some scenarios, like methods that interacts with UI elements.
2. If you don't wrap the call in `Task.Run`, the asynchronous method will be invoked on the current thread. This is unacceptable in other scenarios, like when dealing with asynchronous methods with blocking behavior ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-the-ui-thread)).

You can't just write code mindlessly, with zero awareness about the context in which the code runs. Instead of searching for the elusive silver bullet, it might be more productive to educate yourself by reading a book (paper or digital), or some online material that covers the topic systematically. Don't expect to learn everything from 3-minutes-to-read articles.

Comment: I don't consider myself writing code mindlessly, I do find myself in a hard place finding "the right way" when it comes to "glueing" async code to synchronous code. Your answer might be correct, but it doesn't answer my question I am afraid. Does 1) **guarantee** it will never deadlock? Or could the wrapped call still end up on the main thread if that thread was selected by the task scheduler to execute the lambda on? And what about setting the synchronization context to null explicitly? Would that **guarantee** it will not deadlock?

Comment: PS: I hope you do realize that your suggestion "reading a book paper or digital" is somewhat hard, since there is simply too much to find on this topic where it is very very hard for a programmer to separate garbage from something that actually carries truth in it. It still seems to me that microsoft "tried" to make things simpler with async await, and succeeded for 99%, and left that one percent up for poor souls to figure out themselves, over and over again

Comment: 1) No, because there's BCL and library code outside of your control. The BCL is generally safe, but they did have one slip through years ago with `HttpClient` on mobile platforms. Library code is hit-and-miss; some libraries just don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` at all (looking at you, EF Core).

Comment: Setting the SyncCtx to null will prevent the deadlock. There's a bigger question than preventing deadlock, though: "will it work?" - and that entirely depends on what code is being run. Does the code require running on the UI thread? Does it require a SyncCtx? Does it work correctly when resuming on a thread pool thread? In particular, a null SyncCtx can cause parallelism when there wasn't any previously. I recommend reading [my async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [don't block](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) posts

Comment: Alright, enough for now I think, I will going to spend some more time trying to drill down to the point where I still don't "really" understand what's going on, but at this moment I simply don't know how to ask the correct follow up question. Thanks for the info though, it clarified a few things up at least

Comment: @bas I would also like to mention my personal opinion that sync-over-async deadlocks are not a serious problem. You can read my arguments at the bottom of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously/40855230#40855230) (by Diego Torres), that I edited and expanded a few hours earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The original version is fine **if your assumption is true**; if all the awaits have been configured to not use the captured context then that sort of deadlock won't occur when you block for the result.

It's easy to miss one, though, and one is all it takes (could be in some third-party library, e.g.).

Also, use GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of Result for nice exceptions instead of AggregateException.