# What is the different between calling Task.Run() vs. DoSomethingAsync()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

What is the difference between these two:

```cs
Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(path));

File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
```

I would expect the second one to be faster, sure, but generally is there any security reason I should *not* use the first method? I'm using `File.ReadAllText` as an example but the focus of this question for me is the asynchronous part.

Comment: The first one will consume a thread pool thread for the whole operation, the second one will be able to leverage asyncronious IO and allow the thread to do work while waiting for IO if the underlying operation is actually async. In my experience though `File.ReadAllTextAsync` should be used with caution when working with local file system - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218926/2501279 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the two I would categorize like this

1. `File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);`
   performs a non blocking async operation that immediately return a Task which can be awaited
2. `Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(path));`
   performs a synchronous blocking operation but offloads it to a new thread from the thread pool

Given these differences its obvious why `File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);` is better in case where many i/o operations happen as the `Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(path));` will hold a thread until the operation is completed.

**Summary**

both methods will perform non-blocking operations on the main thread the difference is that `Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(path));` will tie up a thread for the duration of the operation.

Comment: Extremely clear, thank you! Glad to learn a little more about the intricacies of asynchronous programming. It's something I always wished they spent more time on during my education.