# C# Async IO executing synchronously on Windows

Tags: c#, asynchronous, io

According to the .NET documentation, async IO commands can be used to execute File operations in parallel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/using-async-for-file-access#parallel-asynchronous-io

However, a small modification of the above shows that this is not the case:

```cs
  public static async Task SimpleParallelWriteByteAsync()
        {
            var rootFilePath = "C:/temp/asynctest2";
            var fileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100;


            if (Directory.Exists(rootFilePath))
                Directory.Delete(rootFilePath, true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(rootFilePath);
                        
            var buffer = new byte[fileSize];
            new Random().NextBytes(buffer);


            IList<Task> writeTaskList = new List<Task>();

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
            for (int index = 0; index <= 10; index += 1)
            {
                string fileName = $"file-{index:00}.txt";
                string filePath = Path.Combine(rootFilePath, fileName);
                writeTaskList.Add(File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, buffer));
            }
            var timespanLoop = sw.Elapsed;
            await Task.WhenAll(writeTaskList);
            var timespanAfterWhenall = sw.Elapsed;

            Console.WriteLine($"loop {timespanLoop} after when all {timespanAfterWhenall}");
        }
```

The output of this will return:

```
loop 00:00:05.6234609 after when all 00:00:05.6254815
```

on windows.

This same behavior of little difference between these numbers I have reproduced on a Desktop with a local SSD, a network drive, net472, net6.0 and net8.0 (please run locally to reproduce!).

However, converting a line to:

```
writeTaskList.Add(Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, buffer)));
```

will give us the expected parallelised output of:

```
loop 00:00:00.0089046 after when all 00:00:01.2339927
```

On linux, the behaviour works correctly:

```
00:00:00.0082008 after when all 00:00:03.0910144
```

My question is what is controlling this? Why is the .NET documentation wrong/misleading? In my understanding, the asynchronous file operations were not executed in a thread, but a call was sent to the operating system to write the file asynchronously, then the operating system would notify .NET when it was completed, as per: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: The asynchronous filesystem APIs [were improved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-the-ui-thread/63218926#63218926 "Why File.ReadAllLinesAsync() blocks the UI thread?") on .NET 6 and later.

Comment: This is using .NET 6.0

Comment: I wonder if you're hitting some conditions which forces async IO to be done synchronously: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/previous-versions/troubleshoot/windows/win32/asynchronous-disk-io-synchronous. Are you writing to a compressed/encrypted folder perhaps? Also this one is interesting: "On Windows, any write operation to a file that extends its length will be synchronous."

Comment: Possibly the path is a remote share, and taking some time to actually create the file? File creation is synchronous. The source code shows proper async operation for the actual write https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/71344cea37d84bb403d3d303b2add9e6135c539c/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/File.cs#L1063 and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/71344cea37d84bb403d3d303b2add9e6135c539c/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/RandomAccess.Windows.cs#L331

Comment: Have retested on a local SSD, net8.0, net6.0 and net framework and same behaviour in all of them. Please rerun on your local hardware!

Comment: Report it as a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

Comment: @Charlieface I don't understand how this could be a dotnet runtime bug, seems much more likely there is an error in my code/setup?

Comment: I can't see an issue, and I also see the same results. I suspect though that @Ilian is right, that because the increase in size is significant, it becomes synchronous (this is a kernel issue, and can only be avoided by using `SetFileValidData` which is admin only). Having said that, it seems to make no difference whether the file already exists at tht size, so maybe it's something else.

Comment: @Charlieface  In linux I get the expected result: loop 00:00:00.0082008 after when all 00:00:03.0910144

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/98893

Answer (score -5):

I think what is misleading is not the documentation, but the difference between running async and running async/awaited.  In the original code, the file write is indeed done async, on it's own thread separated from the context that is awaiting it. In your modified code you are firing the task, but not waiting for the result.

What I think people miss in the async/await pattern is that it creates threaded code, but retains the synchronous programming practices that people are more comfortable with.

For example, if you watch the thread count, your modified version will spawn a new thread for each 'index' in the loop without waiting on the result, whereas in your original, it will spawn one additional thread for each iteration of the loop, and wait for it's completion.

Comment: *"it creates threaded code"* - Nope. [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: I used the term thread for convenience.  In reality a thread carries too much baggage to be used in every async, and in many cases alternate methods are applied.  However, it does not invalidate the core assumption made: async/await is little more than veneer used to simulate synchronous code behaviors with asynchronous code ( because closures, semaphores and other threaded implementations have proven to be too difficult to get widely adopted )

Comment: You literally said it will spawn a new thread, how can that not mean threads?! Also, we need specific language here, if you don't mean threads, then don't use that term as it is confusing.

Comment: honestly, my experience is that not enough people understand why traditional threading is less than ideal, and that modern schedulers mask so much of the details that what constitutes a 'thread' in modern platforms has become, but heh, we can be pedantic about things too, I'm fine with that :).

Comment: How is the documentation not misleading? It's claiming to support parallel operations but the timestamps suggests it doesn't. `WriteAllBytesAsync` is supposed to use IO completion ports which can write asynchronously and in parallel without extra threads. Clearly, this is not the case with OP's example. Btw, OP is just using Task.Run in his example to demonstrate what should have happened if `WriteAllBytesAsync` can be executed in parallel.

Comment: "whereas in your original, it will spawn one additional thread for each iteration of the loop, and wait for it's completion." `writeTaskList.Add(File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, buffer));` should not spawn an additional thread and it should not wait for its completion. That's why it's called WriteAllBytesAsync. It should be using IO completion ports under the hood.

Comment: @Ilian can confirm this works in Linux and runs asynchronously as expected!